# Sequence 2 asyncio function calls in python

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, sequence, python-asyncio

Question: when I call **generateCSVFromIncidentIdsWithArgs(list)** twice with 2 different lists lets say "list1" and "list2", though the first list response appears correctly, the second list response has the results of list1 as well. I am not sure which variable to reset before making the second call so that the second list call appears without mixing the first list results.

function definition: function fetches response from a url with provided IDs in list

```
   async def fetch(self, url, incident, session, csv):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
             self.format_output(incident, await response.read())


    async def bound_fetch(self, sem, url, incident, session, csv):
        # Getter function with semaphore.
        async with sem:
            await self.fetch(url, incident, session, csv)

    async def run(self, r, csv):
        url = self.conversations_url
        tasks = []
        # create instance of Semaphore
        sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1000)
        sslcontext = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
        sslcontext.load_cert_chain('certificate.pem',
                           'plainkey.pem')

        # Create client session that will ensure we dont open new connection
        # per each request.
        async with ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=sslcontext)) as session:
            for i in r:
                # pass Semaphore and session to every GET request
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.bound_fetch(sem, url + str(i), i, session, csv))
                tasks.append(task)

            responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            return responses
```

function call:

```
def generateCSVFromIncidentIdsWithArgs(list):
    incident_list = list
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(incident_list, True))
    loop.run_until_complete(future)


generateCSVFromIncidentIdsWithArgs(list1)
generateCSVFromIncidentIdsWithArgs(list2)
```

Comment: That's strange. Can you provide a minimal and **runnable** example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately the code is huge and lot of dependencies are there, but I figured the results are getting mixed up as I am doing lot of xml processing inside self.format_output(incident, await response.read()) which is taking a long time. If I just return the response.read() without processing, the results come in the expected order.